# Quadratic forms of two real matrices are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

I have the expression $$x^TAx=x^TBx$$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$ and $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. In addition, $A$ is known to be symmetric.

What can be argued for matrix $B$?

Comment: I recommend that next time, please input your progress too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$  \frac{1}{2}   \left( B + B^T  \right)  = A $$

first, in general, square matrices. $$ x^T (E+F) x = x^T Ex + x^T F x  $$

Next, if $G^T = - G.$ Remember that the transpose of a scalar ( a one by one matrix) is itself.
$$ x^T G x = ( x^TGx)^T = x^T G^T x = - x^T G x, $$ so
$$ 2 x^T G x = 0. $$ The skew symmetric part of a square matrix contributes nothing to the quadratic form, only the symmetric part contributes.

Comment: Have you used that $A$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 0):

$x^TAx=x^TA^Tx$ $[$ $A$ is symmetric $]$
$=(x^TAx)^T=(x^TBx)^T=x^TB^Tx.$

$\Rightarrow x^TBx=x^TB^Tx$

Therefore, $B$ is also a real symmetric matrix.

**Edit:**

Combining the above argument with @Wills answer,

We Get $A=B.$

Comment: So essentially $A=B$.

Comment: I combined Will's answer that claims that $  \frac{1}{2}   \left( B + B^T  \right)  = A $ with yours.

Comment: @ApPs can you solve to get that?

Comment: Is $x^T A x = x^T B x$ supposed to be true for all $x$, or just one?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @ApPs Accept Will's answer.

Comment: Is $  \frac{1}{2}   \left( B + B^T  \right)  = A $ for any square matrices $A$, $B$, or only for the case that $A$ is symmetric? I think it's only for the symmetric case.